# Discord.js try to read file in place of sending it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried to make a file randomizer command and it result in a file reader command that give error because of the strange tokens on the file (because js think the file is a string or something) that js can't understand

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
    name: 'name',
    description: 'description',
    aliases: ['aliase'],
    usage: '[command]',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message) {
        const fileType = ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'mp4', 'mov'];
        const Rfile2 = fs.readdirSync('/app/commands/Database').filter(file => fileType.includes(file.split('.').pop()));
        for (const file of Rfile2) {
            const Rfile = require(`/app/commands/Database/${file}`);
            const randomFile = Rfile(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) * Rfile.length);
            message.channel.send(' ', {
                files: [randomFile]
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: srry if I said something strange but I'm not a english native speaker

Comment: What's the error and where is it happening?

Comment: @JasonKim the error is 'SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token' and a arrow pointing at the content of the .gif (unreadable symbols)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the node require function on a video/image file. The require function is used load JavaScript source files, .node binaries or JSON files. With discord.js you can simply specify the file path and name and it will send it for you as seen in the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send).